# Styling a YUI Split button

Tags: javascript, css, yui, split, button

I want to use split buttons for a left
side menu. I tried adding the class following.

```
<STYLE TYPE="text/css"> .catbutton { display: block; } </STYLE>
```

The buttons were the right width but the menu arrow was the section taking up
the variable width. Not only was it ugly but the menu activation section was in
the correct place on the far right. Clicking on the triangle which was floating
in the middle did not work.

I was thinking that maybe I could add a `<br/>` element after the button using JS.  I am not having any luck.

Help is appreciated.

Comment: Can you clarify what you actually want to do? Your explanation is a bit difficult to follow.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `width: 95%;` to the button style?